# When should I use HttpRequestMessage as parameter in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When do I use the first action?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(HttpRequestMessage message)
{

}
```

I nearly always see only this way. Maybe because it easily maps to a restfull url?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id)
{

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(HttpRequestMessage message)
```

is equivalent to:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put()
```

The `HttpRequestMessage` parameter is automatically bound so that you can get hold of request information in your controller method if you need to ([source](http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2013/06/26/accessing-http-request-from-asp-net-web-api/)). If you don't need to access it, omit it.

If you need to pass an `id`, you will need:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(HttpRequestMessage message, int id)
```

Comment: Thanks, accessing the request makes sense now e.g. checking a token.

Comment: @HelloWorld You can also access the request from the Request property on the Controller.  Passing a request in as a parameter is just for those of us who think it looks prettier that way :-)

Comment: @DarrelMiller Ok even better then.